# C: IFS System() Vulnerability

Tags: c, security, ifs

For educational reasons I have to exploit an C-Code

The Programm set the egid first, and then the vulnerability with the `system("/usr/bin/...");` Command.

So I made an 'usr' executeable in my Home-Directory and set the Path to the Home `PATH=$HOME:$PATH`

And I want to change the IFS Variable in the bash to /: `export IFS='/'`

Unfortunatelly, when i call the C-Programm: my exploit doesn't work

Is anybody able to tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is one of those situations where you should show what you've tried as an SSCCE (a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/)), both to demonstrate that you've put some effort into the question and to allow us to see what you're doing.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we are studying at the same university, because I am currently confronted with the same problem. I don't want to give you the whole solution, because that would be too easy =)

Your IFS variable is not ignored, but it doesn't work as you might think. When you call the C-Programm there is an additional output in the shell, which refers to the lesspipe. With the information in [this link](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/lesspipe/) [and this german link](http://www.linux-community.de/Internal/Artikel/Print-Artikel/LinuxUser/2002/04/lesspipe) you are able to solve the challenge1 ;)

Comment: Is there only one vulnerability? I dont see the vulnerability in cat.c

Comment: The cat example can easily be solved by adding entries to the PATH variable

Answer (score 2):

Add the IFS as part of your program's call to `system()`. System executes the code with `/usr/bin/sh -c`. So you can do similar to what you'd in the shell prompt.

```
system("export IFS='/'; /usr/bin/cmd");
```

Note that once the child process is terminated, the IFS set will no longer be available in the parent.

Comment: I cant change the String in the System Command. I have to exploit it. So i want the given system("/usr/bin/...") redirect to my usr executable. Similar it work with relative paths in system("./myProg"). i tought with changing the IFS Variable i can do this in this case too? Am I Wrong?

Comment: Can you post a complete code? Am not sure what exactly you want you achieve?